# How can I program MATLAB to calculate the argument of a cubed tangent function?

Tags: matlab

I need to solve tan^3(w)=tan(s) for w where s= 1.5 radians or 16.845 degrees. I need to write a line of MATLAB code for this operation but do not know an equivalent form of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

```
solve('tan(x)^3==tan(1.5)','x')
```

Answer:

```
                                      1.1783511187702876557436189917532
- 1.3391755593851438278718094958766 + 0.35610550401885024116569451380696*i
- 1.3391755593851438278718094958766 - 0.35610550401885024116569451380696*i
```

One real solution, and two complex solutions.

(This was tested in Matlab R2012a)

Comment: More details about the analytical solution: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28tan%28x%29%5E3+%3D%3D+tan%283%2F2+radians%29%29

Answer (score 0):

To solve the equation without toolboxes, you can use e.g. `fzero` to find where both sides of the equation are equal.

```
%# define the function that should be equal to zero
%# i.e. subtract the sides of the equation from one another
fun = @(x)tan(x)^3-tan(1.5)

%# solve the function with initial guess 0
fzero(fun,0)
ans =
    1.1784
```

Comment: Note that `fzero` will only find real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
w = atan(tan(1.5)^(1/3))
```